# what do you call those list in node.js site

Tags: node.js

I apologize to ask this question,I am still newbie to node.js and trying to learn on it..I am just confuse in http://nodejs.org/api/ are they all api or module? if we use this in our app.js
**var http = require('http');** 
are calling we calling the api or the module ?please enlighten.are module and api are just the same ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The http api is the set of functions that the http module exposes, IE. through `module.exports`.